# Linux and shared libraries, linking vs dlopen - symbol visibility

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I work on Linux. When my application links to the shared library (which doesn't hide symbols) all symbols from that library are visible. A shared library can also be loaded at runtime using `dlopen`. Is it possible to control symbols visiblity using `dlopen` mode parameter or I always have to get desire symbol using `dlsym` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is exceedingly unclear.

If you `dlopen` the library, then about the only way to get to *any* of its symbols is via `dlsym`.

However, if you `dlopen` a library with `RTLD_GLOBAL`, then its symbols become available for *subsequently* loaded libraries *without* using `dlsym`.

For example, if `libfoo.so` defines symbol `foo`, and if you `dlopen("libfoo.so", RTLD_GLOBAL|...);` and later `dlopen("libbar.so", ...)` which *uses* `foo`, that would work -- `libbar.so` will be able to use `foo` from `libfoo.so` without doing any `dlsym` calls.